# Browser inconsistencies

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using the wp ecommerce plugin and i'm having problems with the rating area:
Here's how it's suppose to look like:

[image]

Here are screenshots of the problem:
firefox:

[image]

IE7:

[image]

IE8 & IE9:

[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/33er0yf.jpg]

Please [see the site](http://goo.gl/Gx9hj)

Comment: can you add a link on wordpress plugins directory to this plugin ? Same problem with google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from the span with id="vote_total_XX", try to remove the float="left" at line  299.

Comment: It worked thank you so much! I'm not sure why the plugin developer put the float: left; there.. 

also i'm not sure what you mean by: can you add a link on wordpress plugins directory to this plugin ? Same problem with google chrome

Comment: I mean where you find this module ^^, and i see the same problem in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In [this CSS](http://beautyspecialist2u.com/wp-content/themes/BeautySpecialist/wpsc-default.css?ver=3.8.6.419073) you have the following rule for `<span>`:

```
span {
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

This forces `(0)` to be at the left of the images. More over there is a `<span>` in `<span>`, so both IE and FF try to push `0` even more to the left of `()`. When I set `float: none;` everything worked as expected.

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is your friend for such cases – I highly recommend.